What's the current direction through cap in this small signal analysis of this first stage amplifier?
Consider the circuit in this netlist. Assume all transistors are operating in saturation, \$V_{Tn} = │V_{Tp}│=V_T\$,
\$\lambda ≠ 0\$ but \$\gamma = 0\$ (neglect body effect). Neglect all parasitic capacitances and consider only the two
capacitances \$C_{L1}\$ and \$C_{L2}\$.
Find the transfer function expressed in first stage and  the poles of the circuit.

Answer:
To find the transfer function \$ \frac{V_{\text{out}}}{V_{\text{in}}} \$ of the two-stage CMOS amplifier and identify the DC voltage gain and poles, we proceed step by step:
1. Small-Signal Modeling of the Circuit
First Stage:
Capacitors:

\$ C_{L1} \$: Connected from node \$ D1 \$ to ground.
\$ C_{L2} \$: Connected from \$ V_{\text{out}} \$ to ground.

2. Deriving the Transfer Function
First Stage Analysis:
\$V_s\$ is the source of \$M_{n1}\$
\$\Rightarrow V_s = V_x\$
$$
  i_{d_{n1}} = -g_{m_{n1}} v_s + \frac{v_{D1} - v_s}{r_{o_{n1}}}
  $$
$$
  i_{d_{p1}} = \frac{v_{D1}}{r_{o_{p1}}}
  $$

KCL at Node \$ D1 \$:
$$
  -g_{m_{n1}} v_s + \frac{v_{D1} - v_s}{r_{o_{n1}}} + \frac{v_{D1}}{r_{o_{p1}}} + s C_{L1} v_{D1} = 0
  $$

KCL at Node \$ V_x \$:
$$
  \frac{v_{\text{in}} - v_s}{R_S} = g_{m_{n1}} v_s - \frac{v_{D1} - v_s}{r_{o_{n1}}}
  $$


However, some of classmates think KCl at node D1
$$
  -g_{m_{n1}} v_s + \frac{v_{D1} - v_s}{r_{o_{n1}}} + \frac{v_{D1}}{r_{o_{p1}}} - s C_{L1} v_{D1} = 0
  $$

Both your KCL equations seem correct. Your classmates seem to have got it wrong with the sign of the capacitor current.
